# htaccess rewrite base url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Anyone out there good with htaccess and mod rewrite - i need your help!

I need to rewrite the base part of a url.

for example all requestst to http://domain1.com need to go to http://domain2.com

The requests will typically be in the form as follows:

http://domain1.com/main/test?q=1

i then need to go to http://domain2.com/main/test?q=2

Pleas help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both domains routed to the same server? What is the pattern for changing the q parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect for http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]

# redirect for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

`R=301` will redirect with https status 301
`L` will make last rule
`NE` is for no escaping query string
`QSA` will append your existing query parameters

`$1` is your REQUEST_URI

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting URL's across multiple domains? I'm not entirely sure this can work, considering Apache's request-handling algorithm. You're looking for a *redirect*, not *rewrite*.