# How to domain redirect in apache?

Tags: apache, server

I'm trying to redirect domain-a to domain-b. So when the user types in domain-a, it will lead them to domain-b. I tried using an HTACCESS file and I'm not having any luck. So  here is what I put in the server config file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin support@domain-b.com
        ServerName domain-a.com
        ServerAlias www.domain-a.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain-a.com/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

        # Testing the rewrite
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-a\.com$ [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-a\.com$
        RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain-b.com\.com\/" [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess rewrite base url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982477/htaccess-rewrite-base-url)

Comment: Can the mod_rewrite be in the config file?

Comment: In your httpd.conf, outside the `<VirtualHost>`, you must include the mod_rewrite module.  The includes do not go inside the `<VirtualHost>`.  Note also that if you are going to redirect `domain-a` completly, you do not need to define DirectoryIndex, DocumentRoot, Directory, ...  Just keep the log and the RewriteRule.